# Doxygen image borders

Tags: css, doxygen

I do have a project with configured documentation generation with doxygen.
Documentation involves a lot of figures which sometimes clashes with background. Is it possible to add a border for all figures in document? Which CSS objects should I change? Figures are inserted using this command:

```
 ![ ](01_demo.png)
```

Resulting html:

```
 <div class="image">
 <img src="01_demo.png" alt="01_demo.png"/>
 <div class="demo caption">Demo caption text</div></div>
```

There is a class in CSS file:

```
 .image
 {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

I can add border to it, but in that case caption will also have it.
Can I somehow get a border only around image itself?

Solution:
I've added a custom /figure tag to doxygen configuration file:

```
ALIASES += figure{2}="<div class="figure">![\2](\1)</div>"
```

Changes to css file:

```
.figure img {
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #879ECB;
}
```

Usage:

```
\figure{demo.png, Demo caption}
```

Comment: my solution does not work?

Comment: I does. But it adds border to all images in document. Including logos, warning symbols, etc. I've decided to add a new div and put it inside custom tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible with the following code

```
.image img {
    border: 1px solid #000;    
}
```

If you want some space between the border and image, add padding.

Here is a fiddle to try: https://jsfiddle.net/6ou62urk/